# How to pass dynamically props from one child component to another on the parent page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have two child components I have to pass dynamically props from first child to parent and from parent to second child.

**Parent**

```
<script>
  data: () => ({
   model: {}
  }),
  methods: {
    changeData(payload) {
      this.model.personalData = {...payload}
    }  
  }
</script>
<template>
  <first-child @changeData="(payload) => changeData(payload)"/>
  <second-child :enter-object="model" />
</template>
```

**Child one**

```
<script>
  data: () => ({
   model: {}
  }),
  methods: {
    changeData() {
      this.$emit("changeData", this.model);
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <v-text-field v-model="model.name" @input="changeData()">
  <v-text-field v-model="model.email" @input="changeData()">
</template>
```

**Child two**

```
<script>
  props: {
    enterObject: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    model: {}
  }),
  watch: {
    enterObject: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        Object.assign(this.model.personalData, this.enterObject.personalData);
      }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="model.personalData.name || model.personalData.email">
      <span class="mr-3">{{ model.personalData.name }}</span>
      <span>{{ model.personalData.email }}</span>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      No data
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I get data in parent component with no problem, but this data doesn't pass to second child, why I have always "No data" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the value of the object using this.$set for more about object reactivity click [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

your Parent component should be like this:-

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-forked-665ybu?file=/src/components/Parent.vue:0-510) is the working example

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <first-child @change-data="(payload) => changeData(payload)" />
    <second-child :enter-object="model" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import FirstChild from "./FirstChild";
import SecondChild from "./SecondChild";
export default {
  data: () => ({
    model: {},
    compKey: 0,
  }),
  components: {
    FirstChild,
    SecondChild,
  },
  methods: {
    changeData(payload) {
      this.$set(this.model, "test", payload);
      //this.model.test = payload;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: hey i edited the answer please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and found a few things:

You need to create "personalData" inside the model in "childTwo".

```
<template>
  <div>
    // I changed the validation for personalData
    <div v-if="model.personalData">
    <span class="mr-3">{{ model.personalData.name }}</span>
    <span>{{ model.personalData.email }}</span>
    </div>
  <div v-else>No data</div>
 </div>
</template>

export default {
  props: {
    enterObject: {
    type: Object,
    required: false,
    default: () => ({})
  }
},
data: () => ({
  model: {
    personalData: {}
  }
}),
watch: {
  enterObject: {
    deep: true,
    handler() {
    // Add a validation in the handler, you can use Object assign inside the validation.
      if(this.enterObject) {
        Object.assign(this.model.personalData, this.enterObject.personalData)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's worked for me.I hope it helps you.